# vim remap key mapped by a plugin

Tags: vim, shortcuts

In vim, I have a key mapping conflict. The `:map` command gives me:

```
n  <C-N>       * :<C-U>YRReplace '1', p<CR>
ov <C-N>       * :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

How can I clear the first mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear the mapping:

```
:nunmap <C-N>
```

To also have the NERDTree mapping in normal mode:

```
:nnoremap <C-N> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

---

Plugins (should) have a check for existing mappings; with this, you can also often solve this by creating a dummy mapping for the first one, so that it doesn't take the `<C-N>` mapping, e.g. (non-functional demonstration):

```
nmap <Plug>DisableYRReplace <Plug>YRReplace
```

Comment: I've added `nunmap <C-N>` to my `.vimrc` and it complains about the inexisting mapping. The plugin may be not yet loaded at this time ? (I've placed it after the pathogen' `infect` command)

Comment: Right. You either have to first explicitly `:runtime plugin/<name>.vim` beforehand, or place the `:nunmap` to `~/.vim/after/plugin/<name>.vim`.

Answer (score 5):

In the $VIMRUNTIME directory (~/.vim/ on unixen, $HOME/vimfiles on windows), create a directory called "after/plugin" and create a file called, for example, "~/.vim/after/plugin/unmap-plugin-keys.vim" containing your settings, like `unmap <C-N>`.

Vim loads all its config files - settings, plugins, syntax,... - and then loads all files in the "after" directory so the after files override the standard ones.
see `:help after-directory`